# Excel 2016 Find and Replace with miscellaneous character

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I have a set of data that was imported from a pdf.  When the data was brought into excel, it placed a period instead of a comma in a number.  For example 1.334.10.  I can find the problem with the control+f by using *.*.  However, when I try to replace the first "." and not the second, I cannot do the same.  I have tried to replace with *,*.  but this just puts the literal characters in the cell.  I have tried to use just the "," however, it then gets rid of the first 4 characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [SUBSTITUTE()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-substitute-function).

You can convert all the data with a formula like `=SUBSTITUTE(A3,".",",",1)`.

The "1" restricts the substitution to only the first instance.  The result will be text, not a number, so you might need to wrap it in a `VALUE()` function:

`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,".",",",1))`

which will convert the text to a number. Text is usually left justified in the cell and numbers are right justified, barring any user-applied formatting.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!  I had some figures that weren't larger than 1000, so I just sorted the data before and applied the formula to those cells that were affected.  Not the most efficient, but saved me a ton of time.  I probably could have applied an "If/Then" test, but I wasn't sure how to do that with text.  Thanks so much for your help.